# how to i set a store a variable that is inside a structure

Tags: c, string, char

what i am trying to do is store a username and password for the administrator so that i can compare what the user types in to what is stored, but i cannot figure out how to store it and use pointer, i thought that i was supposed to use strcpy but now i am just confused...sorry i hope that explains what i need help with

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct profile
{

char First[15];
char Last[15];
char Pwd[10];
char UserName[10];
};

void main_menu(struct profile user[]);
void admin_signIn(struct profile user[]);
void userSignUp(struct profile user[]);
void userSignOn(struct profile user[]);
void quit(struct profile user[]);
void admin_menu(struct profile user[]);

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
   struct profile user[100];
   struct profile *puser;
   puser=&user[0];   
   puser.UserName[0] = "a";
 //puser.Pwd = "password";


   main_menu(user);


  system("PAUSE");
  return 0;
}

void main_menu(struct profile user[])
{
    int choice = 0;

   printf("User Menu\n");
   printf("          \n");
   printf("1 - Admin Sign In\n");
   printf("2 - Sign Up\n");
   printf("3 - Sign On\n");
   printf("4 - Quit\n");
   printf("Enter Choice:");
   scanf("%d", &choice);
   getchar();

   if (choice == 1)
    admin_signIn(user);
    else
       if (choice == 2)
          userSignUp(user);
          else
              if(choice == 3)
                userSignOn(user);
                else
                    if(choice == 4)
                    quit(0);


}

void admin_signIn(struct profile *puser)
{
     int i=0;
     char buff_in[20];
     //UserName="admin";
     //puser->Pwd = "password";
     //user[0].Last = "     ";
     //user[0].UserName="admin";
     //user[0].Pwd="password";


     //do
     //{
     printf("Enter admin user name:");
     fgets(buff_in,10,stdin);
     strcmp((puser+i)->UserName,buff_in);

     printf("Enter admin password:");
     fgets(buff_in,10,stdin);
     strcmp((puser+i)->Pwd,buff_in);
     i++;
     fflush(stdin);

     //printf("the user name is %s:", user[0].UserName);

     //if(user[i].UserName==user[0].UserName && user[i].Pwd ==user[0].Pwd)
              admin_menu(user);
     else
        printf("try again");
    // }while(i<2);
}

void userSignUp(struct profile user[])
{
     int i=0;

 do
 {
     printf("Enter user name that you would like to use:\n");
     gets(user[i].UserName);
     //printf("enter user password:");
     //gets(user[i].Pwd);
     i++;


  }while(i<2);
}

void userSignOn(struct profile user[])
{
     printf("you are in the user sign on menu\n");
}

void quit(struct profile user[])
{
     printf("the is the quit function\n");
}

void admin_menu(struct profile user[])
{
     printf("you are in the admin menu\n");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
puser.UserName[0] = "a";  // This is wrong. Needs to be 'a'
```

`puser.UserName[0]` is of type `char` and `"a"` is of type of `const char*`.

Use [strncpy](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstring/strncpy/) -

```
strncpy( puser.Pwd, "password", strlen("password") );
```

Note: There should be enough room for source and null termination character in the destination.

Comment: thank you so much i was dancing around it, i tried a million different things....char mahesh = "life saver" :)

Comment: @Mahesh: why `sizeof(puser.Pwd)/sizeof(puser.Pwd[0])`instead of `strlen("password)")' ?

Comment: @shannao'neil `char mahesh = "life saver";` isn't syntactically correct either :(

Comment: @Mahesh: ow,yeah. But he must to use `strlen() + 1`,because if the size of string is less than 9 the rest is completed with alot of null bytes,that's no good, since one is sufficient and the application stores "trash" in memory.

Comment: so should i use strlen instead?

Comment: @shannao'neil: Yes. And don't forget: `strlen(string)+1`or you can get overflow.

Comment: strncpy( puser.Pwd, "password", strlen("password") );
is that going to store the word password as the administrator password so that i can compare to it later